# How do I check the flow of internet through ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm using my Ubuntu computer as a wireless receiver, receiving Wifi from my router and sharing my internet through a gigabit switch. How can I check or monitor the speed that I'm sending data to the gigabit switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most simple method is using nethogs :

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
sudo nethogs wlan0
```

[image]

Comment: This would monitor both my wireless draw (personal) and my client draw (ethernet, over a shared network) correct? I'm looking to only monitor the network load from my client computers

Comment: The gigabit switch is connected to your computer right ?

Answer (score 2):

**A Recommendation for Slurm**

---

I have become good friends with an application called [Slurm](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/). It's a nifty application and doesn't eat a whole lot of resources. I actually leave a terminal with it open, pretty much all the time.

Here's a screen shot of it currently running on my system:

[image: Slurm on my current terminal]

[Here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/slurm) is the Ubuntu official page about this for the 15.10 page, if you'd like some more information.

If you'd like to give **Slurm** a try then this can be done by simply opening up the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo apt-get install slurm` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**Note:** You will have to enter your password, when you enter your password there will be no indicator on the screen, no asterisks, and the cursor will not move. This is normal behavior. After entering your password press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again and follow any additional instructions given.

After the installation process you can run `slurm` from the terminal (it's the only way to run it) by simply entering in the commands. This will vary per system and you can find out how your to use `slurm` by entering in the following command into the terminal:

```
slurm -help
```

And pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. To give an example, I would (and did) type the following:

```
slurm -i eth0
```

This is an example of the Slurm help file, as it stands with the current version.

> kgiii@kgiii-desktop:~$ slurm -help
>
> slurm 0.4.3 -
>   https://github.com/mattthias/slurm
>
> usage: slurm [-hHz] [-csl] [-d delay] [-t theme] -i interface
>
> ```
> -h            print help
> -z            zero counters at startup
> -d delay      delay between refreshs in seconds (1 < delay < 300)
> -c            old classic/combined view
> -s            split window mode with stats
> -l            large split window mode
> -L            enable TX/RX 'leds'
> -i interface  select network interface
> -t theme      select a theme
> ```

If you do not know and would like to find the names of your network devices then you can, again, use the terminal. Simple enter this:

```
ifconfig -a
```

And, again, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Now that you've successfully discovered the name of your favorite (in use) ethernet adapter, your output command will look something like the example given above. Just change `eth0` for the adapter name of your choice. The input should look something like this:

```
slurm -i <your ethernet adapter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Graphical software called "System Monitor" in Ubuntu. It is preinstalled software in Ubuntu.
Go to dash and search System monitor to get.

Answer (score 0):

You have several tools one is `bmon`.
Aslo you can export grafs to file

Useful tips you have [here](http://linoxide.com/tools/bmon-install-usage/)

More tool's heve [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu-users.html)